# Lightning is showing unnecessary blue border around slds-grid elements

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system

A blue border is shown around slds-grid elements which disappears when inspector is opened. I have tried applying 'border:0px;', 'border-collapse:collapse' in CSS.
But it didn't work.

```
<div class="slds-grid">
    <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-1">
        <aura:if isTrue="{!and(v.loadTaskDistributionCmp, v.highchartsLoaded)}">
            <div class="slds-box slds-box--small slds-theme--shade slds-text-align--center noBorderRadius df-card"> 
                <c:DFTasksDistribution userTasksData="{!v.userTasksData}"/>
            </div>
        </aura:if>
    </div> 
</div>
<br></br>

<div class="slds-grid">
    <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-1">
        <aura:if isTrue="{!and(v.loadHighTouchContactsCmp, v.highchartsLoaded)}">
            <div class="slds-box slds-box--small slds-theme--shade slds-text-align--center noBorderRadius contactMeetingsData df-card"> 
                <c:DFHighTouchContactsCmp contactMeetingsData="{!v.contactMeetingsData}"/> 
            </div>
        </aura:if>
    </div>
</div>
<br></br>
```

[image: Blue Border around slds-grid elements]

Comment: Can you put your markup please...are you using slds-box?

Comment: @Sarang I have put the markup in edits.

Comment: I removed the slds-box class and the border is not displayed on load. but when i click on the page it is shown again.

Comment: Not sure if it's related, but I'm using a button element in my app that the browser was putting an unwanted blue border around, so I added "outline: 0 !important;" to that element's class, and the blue border went away.  Maybe try putting that in one of your div's classes, and see if it goes away.

Comment: @Florissant53 It did not work.